# Communication between Outlook and Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there a api or anyother means by which we can communicate or sync with Microsoft Outlook server from IBM Worklight Client Mobile Application or from Worklight Server

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no dedicated API. Worklight is a development and runtime platform in which you can write your own code. There is nothing preventing you from calling exchange server API from within a Worklight adapter.